# Custom JMXAuthenticator and Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, rmi, jmx

I want to know if it is possible to use custom JMXAuthenticator in Tomcat.

From this link http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/monitoring.html, I know Tomcat can enable JMX remote with authentication. **But it's based on the password and access files.**

My scenario is a little bit complexity,

1. start tomcat (6.0 is preferred) with JMX remote enabled
2. one of the webapps register its own MBeans (e.g. XXConfig)
3. start my own JMX client and connect to tomcat via RMI
4. **tomcat authenticate the connection via my proprietary protocol (e.g. read from DB, file and etc.)**
5. JMX client r/w JVM info and MBeans if any

Is there any way to redirect the authentication?

I'm almost new to Java and JMX as well, so let me know if I understood and expressed incorrectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

JMX supports customisation of authentication via JAAS.

https://blogs.oracle.com/lmalventosa/entry/jmx_authentication_authorization

You may also find the catalina-jmx-remote.jar useful (search for it on the Tomcat site).